# How can I close a browser window from a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, browser, script, bash-scripting

I would like to open and close windows from a bash script but in my two versions of the code it gets stuck when it opens the first window and does not close the current window and then open the new window. In fact the code only continues its flow if I manually close the current window, otherwise it gets stuck and doesn't continue its flow, I would like to close the window automatically without my intervention but I don't understand why the commands that should close the windows don't work. Here are both versions:

## First

```
#!/bin/bash

# Muestra la fecha y hora actual
echo "Fecha y hora actual: $(date)"

# Pregunta al usuario si desea ejecutar el programa
read -p "¿Deseas ejecutar el programa? (s/n): " respuesta

# Comprueba si la respuesta es 's' (sí)
if [ "$respuesta" = "s" ]; then
    for dia in lunes martes miércoles jueves viernes sábado domingo
    do
        # Abre la pestaña en Firefox
        firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=$dia"

        # Espera 5 segundos para permitir que la página se cargue
        sleep 5

        # Cierra la pestaña
        wmctrl -c "Firefox" -x "Navigator.Firefox"

        # Espera 1 segundo antes de abrir la siguiente pestaña
        sleep 1
    done
fi
```

## Second

```
#!/bin/bash

# Muestra la fecha y hora actual
echo "Fecha y hora actual: $(date)"

# Pregunta al usuario si desea ejecutar el programa
read -p "¿Deseas ejecutar el programa? (s/n): " respuesta

# Comprueba si la respuesta es 's' (sí)
if [ "$respuesta" = "s" ]; then
    for dia in lunes martes miércoles jueves viernes sábado domingo
    do
        # Abre la pestaña en Firefox
        firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=$dia"

        # Espera 5 segundos para permitir que la página se cargue
        sleep 5

        # Cierra la pestaña
        xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox" windowactivate
        xdotool key Ctrl+w

        # Espera 1 segundo antes de abrir la siguiente pestaña
        sleep 1
    done
fi
```

Note: The only difference between the two versions is the part where I close the window.

Comment: You are starting firefox in the foreground.  Add a **&** after the command, here is some more info https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175819/2298

Comment: Oh, thank you, it already works. :)